# seting the time to send email in php

Tags: php, email

i want this script to pping the ip addresses inside the array and then email the result every 9:00 pm, i manage to make the ping and send email codes, but i dont know how to seet the time for the result to be made, please help me wth this problem.

here is the code:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);  
$Email = "kvintijam@gmail.com";

$ipList = array("192.168.2.13", "192.168.2.31", "192.168.2.32", "192.168.2.250", "192.168.2.50", "192.168.2.51","119.73.140.130","192.168.2.253" "192.168.2.9", "192.168.2.10", "192.168.2.2");

$content = "";
foreach($ipList as $ip)
    $content .= exec("ping " . $ip) . "<br />";

mail($Email, 'result', $content, 'From: ismaakeel@gmail.com');

?>
```

Thankyou verymuch, any help will be appreciated

Comment: You want to read about "cron jobs" for this... You use such a job to execute a specific task at a configured time, in this case your php script.

Answer (score 0):

As arkascha mentioned it, if your PHP server run on any UX-based OS, you can add your php script in cronjob table to execute it every day at 9pm.

Basic instructions are:

- open console on your sever and type :
- crontab -e
- it will open up a file. Write down this line at the bottome of the
  file :
- 00 21 00 * * php send_email.php
- exit with saving
- then it will execute your "send_email.php" every day at 9pm

If you don't have Unix on your system, then it's another story.